# How to get substring from revers till a certain character using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have these strings as list of filenames

```
abc-cdef-ijklm-2018.04.02-vendor1.1.0.0
abc-cdef-pqrs-2018.03.22-writer1.2.0.0
abc-cdef-lmno-2017.03.22-reader22.5.0.5
```

I need to extract these sub strings from the each line which is from **reverse** after last 5 letters till the dash `-`.

```
vendor1
writer1
reader22
```

How can do this using simple batch script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to solve this problem. This is a very simple one:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Process the strings (from test.txt file)
for /F "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do call :extract "%%a"
goto :EOF


:extract

REM ECHO ON

set "string=%~1"

rem Extract *the last part* after the last dash
set "string=%string:-=" & set "string=%"

rem Extract *the first part* before the first dot
set "string=%string:.=" & rem "%"

@REM ECHO OFF

echo %string%
exit /B
```

For example, if this is the input file **test.txt**:

```
abc-cdef-ijklm-2018.04.02-vendor1.1.0.0
abc-cdef-pqrs-2018.03.22-writer1.2.0.0
abc-cdef-lmno-2017.03.22-reader22.5.0.5
```

This is the output:

```
vendor1
writer1
reader22
```

This method uses simple substring sustitution to perform the extraction of the desired parts. It is much simpler to *review* the method instead of *explain* it, so you may activate the `ECHO ON` and `@ECHO OFF` commands and check by yourself how the method works.

If you want a further explanation, see [this topic](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429).

Answer (score 0):

If the number of substrings separated by `-` is constant five, following code can be used in batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "_FileName1=abc-cdef-ijklm-2018.04.02-vendor1.1.0.0"
set "_FileName2=abc-cdef-pqrs-2018.03.22-writer1.2.0.0"
set "_FileName3=abc-cdef-lmno-2017.03.22-reader22.5.0.5"

for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ('set _FileName') do (
    for /F "eol=| tokens=5 delims=-" %%C in ("%%B") do (
        for /F "eol=| delims=." %%D in ("%%C") do (
            echo Last part of "%%B" is: %%D
        )
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

Please ignore the most outer **FOR** loop used here only to process the values of an undetermined number of environment variables of which name starts with `_FileName`.

The second **FOR** loop processes a file name as assigned to loop variable `B` in this case by splitting it up into substrings (tokens) using `-` as delimiters as specified with `delims=-`.

Of interest is only the fifth substring. Therefore `tokens=5` specifies that only the fifth substring should be assigned to specified loop variable `A`.

Additionally end of line character is modified from default `;` to `|` to avoid that a file name starting with a semicolon is completely ignored by **FOR**. A file name can't have a vertical bar in name.

So the second **FOR** loop assigns to loop variable `C` the strings:

```
vendor1.1.0.0
writer1.2.0.0
reader22.5.0.5
```

The third **FOR** loop is used to remove everything after first dot by
splitting this string up into substrings using `.` as delimiter with assigning just first substring to specified loop variable `D` as by default with `tokens=` option not explicitly specified. Again `eol=|` is used to avoid that the string is completely ignored by **FOR** if this string starts with a semicolon.

So loop variable `D` holds on this example the string of interest for further processing like just printing it to console.

Here is one more solution using just string substitutions in a subroutine `LastPart` embedded unusually in middle of batch file which is slower, but works also for file names with variable number of hyphen separated substrings.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "_FileName1=abc-cdef-ijklm-2018.04.02-vendor1.1.0.0"
set "_FileName2=abc-pqrs-2018.03.22-writer1.2.0.0"
set "_FileName3=lmno-2017.03.22-reader22.5.0.5"
goto ProcessFileNames


:LastPart
set "FileName=%~1"
rem Get file name without the last six characters.
set "FileName=%FileName:~0,-6%"

rem Remove from file name in a loop everything from beginning to first hyphen
rem character with removing also the hyphen until this is not possible anymore
rem because of file name string not containing anymore a hyphen.

:LastHyphen
set "LastPart=%FileName:*-=%"
if not "%LastPart%" == "%FileName%" set "FileName=%LastPart%" & goto LastHyphen

echo Last part of %1 is: %LastPart%

rem Exit subroutine LastPart and return to calling FOR command line.
goto :EOF


:ProcessFileNames
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ('set _FileName') do call :LastPart "%%B"
endlocal
```

And finally one more variant of above on which the number of characters at end of each file name can be variable too.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "_FileName1=abc-cdef-ijklm-2018.04.02-vendor1.1.0.0"
set "_FileName2=abc-pqrs-2018.03.22-writer1.2.0.50"
set "_FileName3=lmno-2017.03.22-reader22.5.10.15"
goto ProcessFileNames


:LastPart
set "FileName=%~1"

rem Remove from file name in a loop everything from beginning to first hyphen
rem character with removing also the hyphen until this is not possible anymore
rem because of file name string not containing anymore a hyphen.

:LastHyphen
set "LastPart=%FileName:*-=%"
if not "%LastPart%" == "%FileName%" set "FileName=%LastPart%" & goto LastHyphen

rem Get string up to first dot from last part of file name.
for /F "eol=| delims=." %%I in ("%LastPart%") do set "LastPart=%%I"

echo Last part of %1 is: %LastPart%

rem Exit subroutine LastPart and return to calling FOR command line.
goto :EOF


:ProcessFileNames
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ('set _FileName') do call :LastPart "%%B"
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear on how you plan on getting the list of files, so I will show a few methods. Also, this assumes that your file format will be *exactly* as your examples.

let's say your files have a `.PEM` extension, we can then do:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-10 delims=-." %%a in ('dir /b *.PEM') do echo %%g
```

If you have a list of filenames in a file, let's call it `file.txt` where the content is like:

```
abc-cdef-ijklm-2018.04.02-vendor1.1.0.0
abc-cdef-pqrs-2018.03.22-writer1.2.0.0
abc-cdef-lmno-2017.03.22-reader22.5.0.5
```

Then this one should do:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-10 delims=-." %%a in ('type file.txt') do echo %%g
```

But, if you make it clear how you will be accessing the file names, then I can amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the last `-`-delimited item you could use a standard `for` loop like in the below approach. The trick is to replace every `-` by standard delimiter like the <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, and enclosing every part in between `""` in order to protect all the other occurring delimiters. So here is the related code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (use first command line argument)

rem // Read file line by line (empty lines are ignored):
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    rem // Store line string:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Enclose line string within `""` and replace every `-` by `" "`,
    rem    which results in several space-delimited items within `""`: */
    for %%I in ("!LINE:-=" "!") do (
        endlocal
        rem // Store (overwrite) current item with surrounding `""` removed:
        set "ITEM=%%~I"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    rem // Splif off first `.` and everything after from last item:
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=. eol=." %%V in ("!ITEM!") do (
        endlocal
        rem // Return extracted string portion:
        echo(%%V
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This script fails in case the text file contains the characters `*`, `?`, `<`, `>` and `"`.

Given that the script is called `data-extract.bat`, the strings to process are stored in a text file named `data.txt`, and both are placed in the current directlry, run the script like this:

```cmd
data-extract.bat "data.txt"
```

To store the output in another file (different to `data.txt`!), use this:

```cmd
data-extract.bat "data.txt" > "data_NEW.txt"
```